# How to present views above the BottomNavigationBar on a button tap

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, user-interface, view

I've been wondering how to implement a really cool little feature I saw in the Algorand app. I've attached a picture to help illustrate what I mean.

The middle button of the navigation bar at the bottom animates the Send and Receive button onto the view, and then changes it's icon to a cross. These buttons persist when you navigate to other views through the other 4 bottom navigation bar items. And when you click the middle cross button, they disappear.

I tried for a bit to implement this in Flutter. My best attempt was creating my own Bottom Navigation Bar widget for my scaffold, containing the bottom icons and a couple buttons on top, but this seemed really janky. I'm not asking for specific code examples of how to get this done, just rather a point in the right direction of how to do this kind of thing.

Speaking of specific code, their code is actually open source, and the code for the bottom nav bar is here
https://github.com/algorand/algorand-wallet/blob/master/ios/Classes/ViewControllers/Core/Container/TabBar/TabBarController.swift

I've been reading it but unfortunately my Swift is not all that great, working through it line by line. I can make a custom bottom nav bar with Container and Row, and then figure out the onTap behaviours, but it's the presenting two buttons above it that's really blocking me.

[image: Example - Unselected]

[image: Example - Selected]

Comment: I would suggest to wrap the whole Scaffold inside stack and show/hide both the buttons on tap (handling animation and all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scaffold’s `floatingActionButton` parameter is exactly what you’re looking for.

Need two buttons? No problem, it doesn’t have to be a `FloatingActionButton`, it can be any widget, including a `Row`.

```dart
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    FloatingActionButton.extended(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_upward),
      label: Text('Send'),
      onPressed: (){},
      backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent),
    Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8)),
    FloatingActionButton.extended(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
      label: Text('Request'),
      onPressed: (){},
      backgroundColor: Colors.teal),
  ]
),
```

Then to trigger it with a button press, just make it conditional:

```dart
bool appear = false;

...

  floatingActionButton: appear ? Row(...) : null
```

Then you can make it appear or disappear by changing the boolean in your button’s onPressed (and don’t forget to call setState).

Comment: Thank you! I will try this, and the other suggestion and get back to you on how it went. Thank you for your time and examples! :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, just got to this task today as it was deemed a minor cosmetic ticket. This solution literally worked 100% as intended, I can't believe how simple it was. Thank you so much!!